# Is it possible to change constants via Controller/Repository in TYPO3?

Tags: php, typo3, constants, typoscript

I want to change a constant in my Extension in the Controller via **initializeAction**.
It works the half way. Let me explain this:

**TYPO3 Version 8.7.7** Extension build with **Extension Builder**.

If i use the **following code** in my **UserController.php**

```
/**
 * initialize the controller
 *
 * @return void
 */
protected function initializeAction()
{
    ...
    $this->settings['groupDefaultId'] = (string)$newUserGroup[$key]->getUid();
    ...
}
```

and i'll debug it after that in php i got the following Debuginformation:

> settings
>
> array(12 items)
>
> groupDefaultId => '53' (2 chars)

This is the correct value in **PHP** for now. But if i check that value in the Backend under **Template** > **Constant Editor** the value isn't stored any more.

I tried the code above and the [setConfiguration API function](https://api.typo3.org/typo3cms/current/html/class_t_y_p_o3_1_1_c_m_s_1_1_extbase_1_1_configuration_1_1_configuration_manager.html#a67d0c13478d36e47750c5368234d8866).

Comment: I thought that I found a solution, but now it doesn't work anymore - so i deleted my answer. => The "near-solution" was to add the line: `$this->objectManager->get('TYPO3\\CMS\\Extbase\\Persistence\\Generic\\PersistenceManager')->persistAll();` behind the `$this->settings...` line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When i got the new ID, which one i want to set in constants i start the function with the following command:

File: **BaseController.php**

(my UserController extends BaseController, for splitting CRUD-function from Other-functions).

I give a string to it, because at the end of this "way" all Settings are stored as string in $this->settings.

```
// Set current Group Uid as defaultGroupId in Constants
$currentGroupIdHasSetInConstants = $this->setNewGroupIdInConstants((string)$newUserGroup[$key]->getUid());
```

We jumpt to the **setNewGroupIdInConstants function**:

File: **BaseController.php**

```
/**
 * Sets the Constant 'defaultGroupId' with new Value
 *
 * Incoming Requirement for this function:      defaultGroupId = 0 this means
 *                                              defaultGroupId is not set in Constants
 *
 * @param string $newdefaultGroupId          New Default Group ID for New Users
 * @return bool                                 TRUE defaultGroupId has changed | FALSE no changes done
 */
public function setNewGroupIdInConstants(string $newdefaultGroupId)
{
    // Rebuild constants with new property and value
    $newConstantsValue = $this->addConstantsConfigurationForDefaultGroupId($newdefaultGroupId);

    // Add the new property with value to constants
    return $this->userRepository->updateConstants($newConstantsValue);
}
```

First this function jumps to **addConstantsConfigurationForDefaultGroupId function**:

In File: **BaseController.php**

```
/**
 * Build new constants value for defaultGroupId
 *
 * @param string $value                     The new value for defaultGroupId
 * @return string                               The complete Constants value
 *                                              including the defaultGroupId Configuration
 */
public function addConstantsConfigurationForDefaultGroupId($value)
{
    $getConstants = $this->userRepository->fetchConstants()['constants'];
    // This Value has to look like this with the new line (for getting original code incl. \n for constants)
    $buildAdditionalConstant = '
plugin.tx_rmregistration.settings.defaultGroupId = '.$value;

    return $getConstants.$buildAdditionalConstant;
}
```

**fetchConstants function**:

In File: **UserRepository.php**

(Usually it belongs to a SysTemplatesRepository.php, but those one doesn't exist. "Hello Core Team, we need a SysTemplatesRepository ;)".

```
/**
 * Find Constants via sys_template Database Table
 *
 * @return array|NULL           Result is array('constants' => queryResult) or NULL
 */
public function fetchConstants()
{   // 
    // Query Builder for Table: sys_template
    $queryBuilder = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(ConnectionPool::class)->getQueryBuilderForTable('sys_template');

    // Get Constants of Row, where RM Registration is included
    $query = $queryBuilder
        ->select('constants')
        ->from('sys_template')
        ->where(
            $queryBuilder->expr()->like(
                'include_static_file',
                $queryBuilder->createNamedParameter('%' . $queryBuilder->escapeLikeWildcards('EXT:rmregistration/Configuration/TypoScript') . '%')
            )
        );

    // Execute Query and Return the Query-Fetch
    $query = $queryBuilder->execute();
    return $query->fetch();
}
```

Here is my code of the **updateConstants function**

In File: **UserRepository.php**

```
/**
 * Update Constants via sys_template Database Table         ( Updates $this->settings )
 *
 * @param string $constants         The new settings, that has to be stored in $this->settings
 */
public function updateConstants(string $constants)
{
    // Query Builder for Table: sys_template
    $queryBuilder = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(ConnectionPool::class)->getQueryBuilderForTable('sys_template');

    $query = $queryBuilder
        ->update('sys_template')
        ->where(
            $queryBuilder->expr()->like(
                'include_static_file',
                $queryBuilder->createNamedParameter('%' . $queryBuilder->escapeLikeWildcards('EXT:rmregistration/Configuration/TypoScript') . '%')
            )
        )
        ->set('constants', $constants);
    $query = $queryBuilder->execute();

    return ($query > 0) ? TRUE : FALSE;
}
```

Comment: This works, but i have to clear the cache for getting the changed value in frontend. So i [asked a new Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48930674/how-to-clear-cache-for-table-sys-template-with-php-or-typoscript-in-typo3).